# Jenkins plugin not showing up

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

probably a newbish question, but that's what I am. I need to run a post build script, so I installed the [post-build-task plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) onto my Jenkins server (v2.5). For some reason, when I go to the job configuration page, there is no checkbox or anything for the plugin. Is there some common pitfall I am stepping into or something?

Edit: I have restarted the server.

Answer (score 2):

So it was a blatantly simple issue. The job I was working in was a pipeline, and it needed to be a freestyle project.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting will update the plugins..

Comment: check in manage plugins > installed (it will propose for intalled plugins to downgrade or upgrade versions)

Comment: It isn't proposing an upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: Check in project config > `add post build action` options

Comment: Doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: Which I think is the main issue I am having.

Comment: yes i think so.. pls check in config, if you find something about it